# Setting cookies before first load of page in expresses

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

Is there any way to set cookies before first enter to the site? For now I added this code at beginning of every get operation:

```
if(!req.cookies.lang) {
    res.cookie('lang', 'en');
    res.redirect('back');
}
```

Is there any better solutions so there will be no need to add this code at beginning of each get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid code repetition, you can add a middleware that handles that for every `GET`.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.cookies.lang) {
        res.cookie('lang', 'en');
        return res.redirect('back');
    }

    next();
});

/* get routes */
app.get('/some/route', (req, res) => {
    // No need to check cookie, it was checked by the other middleware
    // ... 
});

/* ... */
```